# Quick function to tell database initializer to use local U/P or webhost Username/pass?

Tags: php, database-connection, localhost

I came across a similar question once on SO but didn't mark it and can't find it now.

Currently my `init.php` file looks like this:

```
$db_username = user;
$db_password = pass;
//$db_username = user213124; // webhost
//$db_password = pass214142; // webhost
```

and I alternately comment/uncomment those lines depending on if its running on my test machine's XAMPP installation or on my webhost.

Sometimes I forget, and upload the wrong one, which is always good for a laugh.

I'm sure there's a way to write a short function allowing `init.php` to detect its location and use the appropriate username/pass combo.

The first solution that popped into my head was a simple `if(file_exists()) {}` and checking for something that would ONLY be on my test machine. I'm guessing there's a better way that doesn't prompt disk access though, amirite?

Thank you.

PS - please edit my subject to make it more accurate. Tried my best. Kinda hard to describe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways of accomplishing this, some may be better than others, I think it all depends on your situation.

One way is to check for something in `$_SERVER`. For example, you might user the server name:

```
if ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'my.dev.server') {
    $user = 'dev_user';
    $pass = 'dev_pass';
} else {
    $user = 'other_user';
    $user = 'other_pass';
}
```

You might also consider having a local configuration file, unique to whatever environment you're on. This could be an ini file or php file that just defines the above variables, and is included, but isn't under version control and doesn't get changed very often.

Sometimes people will also define environment variables. There are probably other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ServerAdmin directive of apache to identify my local development machine... Just look how you can set the ServerAdmin of your XAMP server and check

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADMIN']
```

Comment: what happens if you're the admin of both servers?

Comment: then set the Directive on your local machine to something else than your regular email address...